# Convert csv file into Avro format using Python

Tags: python, csv, avro

would you please let me know how can I convert a csv single file into avro format in Python 3?

I have tried Dask library and also PyArrow however the last one was discarded for version details.

Comment: `pyarrow` is what I would recommend. You will need to detail how you tried to installing what versions of things you are using and what errors you encounter. Without that information we can at best guess what your issue is.

Comment: this question has been asked before here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892387/csv-to-avro-using-python  does this help ?

Comment: Look here some examples to covert CSV to AVRO- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425538/20495956